# How can we merge the two selected features in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, python, merge

I have taken one feature and find which are the neighbouring features to the feature which i have taken and then i have combine all those neighbouring features with my feature to make one feature. i have used the following code for finding neighbouring features.

```
import itertools 
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.permutations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
          if geom1.geometry().intersects(geom2.geometry()):
              print geom1.attributes(),geom2.attributes()                
              layer.select(geom1.id())
              geom = geom1.id.combine( geom2.id)
```

But when i am using the **.combine** it is throwing the following errror

```
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'combine'.***
```

So is there any possible way to combine/merge features programatically by using python programming?

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to include your script so that potential answerers are in a better position to help you?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do: `geom1.id()`is not a geometry, it is an index (number). You can use `combine` only with geom1.geometry()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use combine you use the binary predicate union (topological relationships).

```
gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline( [ QgsPoint(1,1), QgsPoint(2,2) ] )
gLine2 = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline( [ QgsPoint(2,3), QgsPoint(5,5) ] )
union = gLine.combine(gLine2) # union
print union.exportToGeoJSON()
{ "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [1, 1], [2, 2] ], [ [2, 3], [5, 5] ] ] }
```

`append`is for lists, not for PyQGIS geometries

```
list_geom = [gLine, gLine2] # append
for geometry in list_geom:
    print geometry.exportToGeoJSON()
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [1, 1], [2, 2] ] }
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [2, 3], [5, 5] ] }
```

but:

```
gLine.append(gLine2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'append'
```

because a PyQgis geometry is not a list

If you want to merge all the features of a layer:

```
geoms = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geoms = geoms.combine(feature.geometry())
print geoms
<qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x12efca9d0> # -> one resulting geometry
```

It is different from:

```
geoms = list() # or []
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geoms.append(feature.geometry())
```

or

```
geoms = [feature.geometry() for feature in layer.getFeatures()]
print geoms
[<qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x12efcab00>, <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x12efcaa68>, <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x12efca8a0>,....]
# a list with all the geometries
```

Comment: i have edited the question.Please once can you give the answer again bec the one code which u have given is not wrking in my condition.

Comment: Thank you. I realised it after i posted the question.Now it is working fine for me.